# How to initialize Browser library with non-default arguments when using 'Get library instance' in Python

Tags: python, robotframework, built-in

I am new with Robotframework. For a project, I am using Python and Robotframework, and [Browser](https://robotframework-browser.org/) library. I am initializing the Browser library in Python like this:

```
self.builtin = BuiltIn()
self.mylibrary = self.builtin.get_library_instance('Browser')
```

Here is my problem: when I import the Browser library like this, it will be initialized with the [default values](https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-browser/Browser.html#Importing). What if I want to pass another value for, for example, `jsextension` or `timeout`?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `get_library_instance` doesn't import the library. If it hasn't already been imported then the keyword will fail.

So, to answer the question of how to import the library with non-default arguments, you must do so with the `Library` setting in a test case, the `Import Library` keyword in a test case, or calling `BuiltIn().import_library` in your python script before attempting to get the instance.